# Why Bootstrap 3 changes camelCase to dashes - is it more readable?

Tags: coding-standards, readability

I'm wondering what's the reasoning behind Bootstrap's decision to [change all camel case names into hyphenated names](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/02/07/bootstrap-2-3-released/) in v3.0. I searched on Google, and looked in a few books, but I can only find opinions one way or the other - no hard data.

Are there any studies that suggest camel case variable names are more readable than dashes, or is this just a matter of personal preference?

Comment: "Readability" may be better defined with wikipedia's metric listing, such as "speed of perception," "perceptibility at a distance," "perceptibility in peripheral vision," "visibility," "the reflex blink technique," "rate of work" (e.g., speed of reading), "eye movements," and "fatigue in reading".

Comment: @Blowski: Where on the page you linked does it discuss the change to hyphenated names? Bootstrap's library appears to be associated with HTML and CSS, where *two-word attributes are always hyphenated by convention.*  They may just be doing it for consistency; all other things being equal, consistency wins.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the question was prompted by a discussion on Hacker News, which was itself prompted by the Bootstrap announcement. There was a lot of opinion on both sides, but no data - hence the question.

Comment: There are lots of things in software design and development that are driven, not by the result of formal studies, but by convention and pragmatism.  That's why defacto standards exist; they arise out of everyday use, and many people discovering over time what works and what doesn't.

Comment: @RobertHarvey agreed, and I do tend to go with convention. The discussion was basically saying that camel case is a bad convention that should be changed because it's less readable.

Comment: Anecdotally, Lisp uses the hyphens and has since the start, and I do remember in their tutorials them touting it as being awesome because it's more "natural".

Comment: I agree that dashes are very readable, but you can't use them universally because in many languages they represent negation or subtraction, so they're not allowed in indentifier names.  Lisp gets away with this because function names are placed *first,* so dash can be used as a function for subtraction.

Comment: @JeffLangemeier Lisp is also case insensitive - this may well factor into the choice of hyphens for word separators.

Comment: @MichaelT It's case insensitive because originally you could only use caps, Lisp predates good ASCII standard.  And the hyphen was standard on all keyboard systems, the underscore wasn't.  So camel case and underscores weren't always possible.

Comment: Well, according to the Hacker News article (where presumably a principal of BootStrap was participating), BootStrap made the change because "in their gut, they felt it was right."  They said they would have made the change earlier, except for backward compatibility concerns.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Further, look at the language that they're integrating with, CSS. CSS already uses hypens in nomenclature, it's almost a no brainer that they'd switch.  So we're again back at your original idea for it, convention and pragmatism.

Comment: I don't know why they chose dashes, but one "advantage" dashes have over both camelCase and underscores is they can be typed without the shift key.

Comment: Just to be clear are we discussing Twitter Bootstrap?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm stealing [Robert's comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186407/why-bootstrap-3-changes-camelcase-to-dashes-is-it-more-readable#comment358758_186407):

> There are lots of things in software design and development that are driven, not by the result of formal studies, but by convention and pragmatism. That's why defacto standards exist; they arise out of everyday use, and many people discovering over time what works and what doesn't.

When it comes to choosing between camelCase and hyphenated names this is particularly true, as studies are inconclusive:

- [To camelCase or under_score](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5090039&contentType=Conference%20Publications&queryText=underscore%20camelcase) - Dave Binkley, Marcia Davis, Dawn Lawrie, Christopher Morrell

  > The study described in this paper shows that although those without training take longer to recognize identiﬁers in the camel case style, all subjects are more accurate when identifying a camel-cased identiﬁer. In addition, subjects trained to use camel casing take less time to identify a camel-cased identiﬁer than an underscore identiﬁer.
  >
  > The next step is to consider higher-level tasks in more realistic settings. One task would investigate the impact of camel casing versus underscores when reading blocks of code. For example, subjects might be asked to search for a particular identiﬁer. Another task would ask subjects to read natural language paragraphs modiﬁed to use camel casing or underscores. This would enable more direct comparisons with previous work done in psychology such as Epelboim et al.
- [An Eye Tracking Study on camelCase and under_score Identifier Styles](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5521745&contentType=Conference%20Publications&queryText=An%20Eye%20Tracking%20Study%20on%20camelCase%20and%20under_score%20Identifier%20Styles) - Bonita Sharif, Jonathan Maletic

  > An eye-tracking study analyzing the effect of identifier style (camel-case and underscore) on accuracy, time, and visual effort is presented with respect to the task of recognizing a correct identifier, given a phrase.  Visual effort is determined using six measures based on eye gaze  data namely: fixation counts and durations.  Although, no difference was found between identifier styles with respect to accuracy, results indicate a significant improvement in time and lower visual effort with the underscore style. The interaction of Experience with Style indicates that novices benefit twice as much with respect to time, with the underscore style.  This implies that with experience or training, the performance difference between styles is reduced.  These results add to the findings of Binkley et al.’s study.  Future work includes conducting more eyetracking studies (with a larger subset of identifiers and larger subject sample), on reading source code consisting  of both identifier styles, in the context of a specific task such as debugging.  Another possible direction is to determine if there is an advantage for a programmer to change their current style to what is determined to be a better  overall style.

  <sub>Note: The study referenced here as Binkley et al. is the first study I linked to.</sub>

Comment: From the second study: "This implies that with experience or training, the performance difference between styles is reduced." to which one can answer "the one that is more readable is the one you use the most." -- Pick a convention and stick with it.